# Combine Navigation UL jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function that will combine two children `ul#level_2`and append them to their parent `li#level_1` within a dropdown `#navigation`.

I currently have the following which does the job, but it means I have to manually target each category. I'm sure there is a far shorter way to produce the same results with very little code.

```
$('li#furniture ul.level_2').children('li').appendTo('li#furniture ul.level_2:first');
$('li#furniture ul.level_2').children('li').not(':first').remove();
```

Here is a shortened version of my current html structure & below is the desired result:

**Simple Current HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="level_1">
        <li class="level_1">
            <div class="subnav_wrapper">
                <ul class="level_2">
                    <li class="level_2">
                        <a href="#">Link A</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
                <ul class="level_2">
                    <li class="level_2">
                        <a href="#">Link B</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>           
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Desire HTML**

```
   <div id="navigation">
        <ul id="level_1">
            <li class="level_1">
                <ul class="level_2">
                    <li class="level_2">
                        <a href="#">Link A</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="level_2">
                        <a href="#">Link B</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>               
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Full Detailed HTML**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ul id="level_1">
        <li class="level_1 furniture">
            <a href="#">Furniture</a>
            <div class="subnav_wrapper">
                <ul class="level_2">
                    <li class="level_2 sofa">
                        <a href="#">Sofa</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
                <ul class="level_2">
                    <li class="level_2 bed">
                        <a href="#">Bed</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>           
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="level_1 bathroom">
            <a href="#">Bathroom</a>
            <div class="subnav_wrapper">
                <ul class="level_2">
                    <li class="level_2 shower">
                        <a href="#">Shower/a>
                    </li>
                </ul>   
                <ul class="level_2">
                    <li class="level_2 bath">
                        <a href="#">Bath</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>           
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: why you are using `not` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```
var wrapper = $(".subnav_wrapper").contents();

$(".subnav_wrapper").replaceWith(wrapper );

$('ul.level_2').children('li').appendTo('ul.level_2:first');
$('ul.level_2').not(':first').remove();
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9nzcsvsu/)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to remove the `.subnav_wrapper`, however, how do I now combine both remaining `ul`?

Comment: Perfect Riad. How would I run this for each individual `<ul id="level_1">`?

Comment: Thanks. you are talking about `id`, So it should be unique. directly access it as `#level_1` or for clearance plz put expected input and output.

Comment: Each `<li class="level_1">` has an extra class i.e `<li class="level_1 kitchen">`. I thought perhaps there was a way to run it through a function and target `this` for each `<li class="level_1">` instead of targeting each unique class. I could easily be wrong.

Comment: make an update of the question and append your new inputs and expected result you want to see.

Comment: ok, you can go now with `$('li.level_1').each(function(){
    //now you get the $(this) as the li itself.
}) ;`

Comment: Thank you again Riad, this is as close as I have gotten.
http://jsfiddle.net/liondedan/1z8ar2k3/

Comment: For some reason my fiddle doesn't quiet seem to work. I think it is almost there.